# Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Tags: angular, typescript

for the below posted code, when i build the project using `ng build --prod --base-href="." --aot --output-hashing=all` i receive the following error:

`property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.`

`Property 'crop' does not exist on type 'unknown'.`

please let me know how to fix it

**note**

in the local version, i do not receive any error, but that happens when i try build the project
**code**:

```
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([k,v]) => v.crop === 'Eiche' || v.crop === 'Kiefer'))
  this.crops = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(res).map(x=> x.crop)))
  this.eppos = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(res).map(x=> x.eppo)))

})
```

**update**:

```
this.subEvtEmitterForAllSubCultures = this._InsecticidesProductsPropertiesService.getEvtEmitterForResponseAllSubCultures().subscribe((d: Object)=>{
  const data:Object = d
  const filtered = data.filter((data) => data.crop == 'Eiche' || data.crop == 'Kiefer');
  
  this.crops = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(filtered).map(x => x.crop)))
  
  this.eppos = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(filtered).map(x => x.eppo)))

})
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using typescript and your lib is not set to a modern enough version in the tsconfig.

Changing it to 'esnext' is the easiest way to confirm that fixes the issue, **however** if this is a production build, you may wish to only include a specific version as esnext will change as time goes on to always include the latest it can:

```
    "lib": [
      ....
      "esnext"
    ],
```

More info can be found here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib

Comment: where can i find `"lib": [` please, in which file is that?

Comment: If i'm correct and you're using typescript you presumably have a tsconfig.json? If so it would go in there.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: for `x.crop` and referring to the code posed above, how can specify a type for `x` please

Comment: That's strictly speaking a separate question, but as it's related i'll try to answer in a comment.

Typescript should be able to infer the types if the 'data' variable is stronly typed. For example, if data is defined as 
`const data:Record<string, MyType> = {}` where `MyType` is:
`
type MyType = {
  crop: string
  eppo: number
}` (this doesn't show well in a SO comment)

the values should then be inferred as a string[] for crops and a number[] for eppo.
You will of course have to adjust for your actual types.

Comment: should i just add type definition to `data`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: i added update section to the question please have a look. i added a type definition to `data` but still the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

i solved it be specifying the `type` as follows, and by adding `esnext`as @MasNotsram mentioned below:

```
const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).filter(([k,v]:any) => v.crop 
=== 'Eiche' || v.crop === 'Kiefer'))

this.crops = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(res).map((x:any) => x.crop)))
this.eppos = Array.from(new Set(Object.values(res).map((x:any) => x.eppo)))
```